# oracle: INTO Clause in Case Statement not working for else option

Tags: oracle

I want to set `ret` '0' or '1' based on condition true or false.I have write following Oracle SQL Query:

```
DECLARE
member_code VARCHAR2(3);
person_id VARCHAR2(3);
ret VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
person_id := 'id1';
member_code := '123';
SELECT CASE  WHEN PER_ID = person_id AND MEM_CODE = member_code THEN '1' ELSE '0' END 
into ret
FROM Table_Persons
WHERE PER_ID = person_id AND MEM_CODE = member_code;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ret);
END;
```

the code works fine if it get the case match and returns '1'.
However code does not return '0' for no case match.Instead it shows error `ORA-01403: no data found`. so, how can i evaluate `ELSE '0'` for no case found case.please help.thanks

Comment: SELECT INTO statement   no rows were returned. Check NVL function.

Comment: I'm puzzled... Your condition is `WHERE PER_ID = person_id AND MEM_CODE = member_code;`. How could you get a record that would yield `0`? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to always return one row use an aggregate function. With your `CASE`  expression you also need `NVL` or `COALESCE` to deal with the NULL value.

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN PER_ID = person_id AND MEM_CODE = member_code THEN '1' END), '0')
into ret
FROM Table_Persons
WHERE PER_ID = person_id AND MEM_CODE = member_code;
```

Or much easier:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
into ret
FROM Table_Persons
WHERE PER_ID = person_id AND MEM_CODE = member_code;
```

which returns the number 1 when found and 0 otherwise. (In case `PER_ID` and `MEM_CODE` are not unique in the table the latter query can result in a value greater than 1. In that case you might want to add `AND rownum = 1` at the end of the query.)